# Creating site with ArcGIS for Server gives Failed to create site. com.esri.arcgis.discovery.servicelib.AGSException?

Tags: arcgis-server, installation, arcgis-10.3, windows-8

I installed ArcGIS for server 10.3 in windows 8 . everything is ok and service is running but when creating a site with manager wizard, the site encounter to the error "Failed to create the site. com.esri.arcgis.discovery.servicelib.AGSException" .How can i solve the problem ?
[image]

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "everything is OK and service is running"? Is this a new installation of ArcGIS Server? Can you access the server's REST API (eg http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest)?

Comment: Is IIS or Apache installed and running? Is it because of your firewall or virus program?

Comment: I could not publish projects thus i can't use rest api .IIS is installed and i disable my firewall and antivirus but couldn't solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

1. uninstall the ArcGIS for Server and delete all of the related folders
2. turn off the antivirus and firewall
3. reinstall the ArcGIS for Server